# How to group latitude/longitude data into different groups based on a shapefile?

Tags: r, geocoding, geospatial, shapefile, point-in-polygon

Original Problem : I have a data set where each row has latitude and longitude within limits of New York. Now I need to group each row into one of the zipcodes in New York. I have shapefiles with all the boundaries available from https://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/inventories/details.cfm?DSID=934.

Adding sample data for latitude, longitude http://pastebin.com/mXntxhK2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`over` / `%over%` works pretty well as @RobertH suggested.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)

# get the shapefile without wasting bandwidth
URL <- "http://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/data/ds_934/zip_codes_shp.zip"
fil <- "nyzips.zip"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)
shp <- grep("shp$", unzip(fil), value=TRUE)
ny <- readOGR(shp[2], ogrListLayers(shp[2])[1], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# you didn't give us data so we have to create some by random sampling
# within the bounding box
ny_area <- as(extent(bbox(ny)), "SpatialPolygons")
set.seed(1492) # reproducible
pts <- spsample(ny_area, 3000, "random")
proj4string(pts) <- proj4string(ny)

# this does the lon/lat to zip mapping
zip_where <- pts %over% ny

# since we fabricated data, not all will be in a zip code since
# ny isn't a rectangle, so we remove the "bad" data
zip_where <- zip_where[complete.cases(zip_where),]

arrange(count(zip_where, POSTAL), desc(n))

## Source: local data frame [602 x 2]
## 
##    POSTAL     n
##     (chr) (int)
## 1   12847    16
## 2   12980    14
## 3   13367    14
## 4   13625    10
## 5   12843     9
## 6   12986     9
## 7   12134     8
## 8   12852     7
## 9   13324     7
## 10  13331     7
## ..    ...   ...
```

Since you provided a sample of your coordinates, here's how to read them in and convert them to the projection of your NY shapefile so you can do the aggregation:

```
pts <- read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mXntxhK2", na.strings="null")
pts <- pts[complete.cases(pts),]
coordinates(pts) <- ~longitude+latitude
proj4string(pts) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
pts <- spTransform(pts, proj4string(ny))

# this does the lon/lat to zip mapping
zip_where <- pts %over% ny

# but since we fabricated data, not all will be in a zip code since
# ny isn't a rectangle, so we remove the "bad" data
zip_where <- zip_where[complete.cases(zip_where),]

arrange(count(zip_where, POSTAL), desc(n))
## Source: local data frame [158 x 2]
## 
##    POSTAL     n
##     (chr) (int)
## 1   11238    28
## 2   11208    25
## 3   11230    20
## 4   10027    19
## 5   11229    17
## 6   11219    16
## 7   11385    16
## 8   11206    15
## 9   11211    15
## 10  11214    14
## ..    ...   ...
```

Comment: Could you give some pointers on how to convert my lat/long format to this xy system?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach:

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
# example data
filename <- system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster")
zip <- shapefile(filename)
set.seed(0)
xy <- coordinates(spsample(zip, 10, 'random'))
plot(zip, col='gray')
points(xy, pch=20, col='red', cex=2)
# 
extract(zip, xy)
```

you can also use sp::over

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm new to R and let me try this out.

Comment: When I try this the last line throws an error: `Error... : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "matrix"’.`

Comment: I'm getting an error with 4th line. http://pastebin.com/xHA1wfHF Error in normalizePath ..

Comment: I was trying '=' instead '<-'. But even after correcting that I'm getting the same error

Comment: You should not use `system.file`. That is to get an example file that ships with R. You should do `zip <- shapefile("nyad_15c/nyad.shp")`